# How does Google Calendar API create auto-generated Event ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api

During an event creation using the Calendar API insert, when an icalUID is provided in the requestBody looks like it is hashed using Base32hex method to generate the event ID:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "id": "_c5pm8pj764p36",
 "created": "2021-05-17T21:54:11.000Z",
 "updated": "2021-05-17T21:54:11.129Z",
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2021-05-16T11:00:00-04:00"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2021-05-16T12:00:00-04:00"
 },
 "iCalUID": "asdfg123",
}
```

How about when no ID is provided so that they are auto-generated? Which metadata and hashing method are used to create the event ID?

Comment: Since they recommend using UUID algorithm that's probably what they use.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino Normally UUID has length of 36 characters (32 hex digits + 4 dashes), but the id generated has different length :(